# Finding minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3 + i \sqrt 7$ over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

$x=\sqrt 3 + i \sqrt 7$

I have come to the following polynomial: $x^4 + 8x^2+100=0$. By Eisenstein criterion, this pol is not irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$, but I don't know how to factor it further? Will be great if I can get some hints.

Comment: Why would that polynomial be not irreducible? The Eisenstein criterion only gives you a sufficient condition for irreducibility, not that the polynomial is reducible if said condition isn’t met.

Comment: I believe the minimal polynomial should be a 4th degree, why are you trying to factor it?

Comment: That polynomial *is* irreducible.

Comment: You can easily finds the root of this polynomial and prove that indeed it's irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: If you're hell-bent on trying to factor it, the rational root theorem tells you it has no rational roots, so if it factors, it must factor into two quadratics. Because it's monic you know the two quadratics would have to be of the form $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$. If you try to solve this system of equations, you won't be able to with rational numbers, thus proving it's irreducible.

Comment: A roadmap. 1) Show that $i\sqrt{21}\in\Bbb{Q}(x)$. 2) Therefore $K=\Bbb{Q}(i\sqrt{21})\subseteq L=\Bbb{Q}(x)$. 3) Conclude $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$ and that the real part of any element of $K$ is rational. 4) Conclude that $x\notin K$, and therefore $[\Bbb{Q}(x):\Bbb{Q}]\ge4$. 5) Conclude that the minimal polynomial has degree four at least.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Think I got enough tips to move forward. Appreciate all your input.